# Change Table View Cell height for iPad only

Tags: swift, ipad, uitableview

I was wondering how to go about this...I want to change the table view cell height only for the iPad size. When I try to change it using Size Classes, it changes it for every single device, not just the one I am in. Do I have to create a whole new story board or is there a way either through code or through Auto Layout to have 2 different tableview cell heights - one for iPhone and one for iPad. I am also using swift in xcode

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `userInterfaceIdiom` to find out if the app is running on iPad

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .Phone:
        // It's an iPhone
    case .Pad:
        // It's an iPad
    case .Unspecified:
        // Something undefined
    }
```

Alternatively, you might also use `UITraitCollection` of the screen.

```
let deviceIdiom = UIScreen.mainScreen().traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom

switch (deviceIdiom) {
    case .Pad:
      // It's an iPad
    case .Phone:
      // It's an iPhone
    case .TV: 
      // It's a AppleTV
    default:
      // Who knows
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider basing it on the size class rather than the device. You can do that via storyboards or in code.

If the height is set by a constraint constant, you can select that constraint and then go to the Size inspector.  To the left of the constant is a gray +. Click that to make it possible to have different values for different size classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width < 768 { //IPHONE
    tableView.rowHeight = 25;
} else { //IPAD
    tableView.rowHeight = 35;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5, there is a slight change in the syntax

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .phone:
                // iPhone
        case .pad:
                // iPad
        case .unspecified:
                // Something else
        default:
            break
}
```